# nvim-completion-manager: neovim shows a Python syntax error in cm.py when opening a new file i despite no actual syntax error in file

Tags: python, nvim

In `~/.config/nvim/plugged/nvim-completion-manager/pythonx/cm.py`, line 151 is

```
        self.nvim.call('cm#complete', name, ctx, startcol, matches, refresh, async=True)
```

I'm using Python 3.8 and copying the file into an online interpreter for Python does not result in any syntax errors, so it confuses me that neovim is interpreting it as such.

While 3.8 is installed, I also found `/usr/lib/python2.7` which may be being used.

I get `Error detected while processing function <SNR>35_on_core_channel_error`
[image: Shows when nvim starts]

When I press enter, it says:

```
Error detected while processing function <SNR>35_on_core_channel_error:
line    1:
```

(doesn't tell me the file or the line code (unless it's just empty).

Pressing enter again:

```
nvim-completion-manger core channel terminated.
```

Then I press enter to go in to nvim.

My `~/.config/nvim/init.vim` is

```
call plug#begin()
Plug 'roxma/nvim-completion-manager'
Plug 'SirVer/ultisnips'
Plug 'honza/vim-snippets'
call plug#end()
```

I tried replacing the leading spaces with tabs but I got the same output.

All of this is followed directly from https://www.linode.com/docs/guides/how-to-install-neovim-and-plugins-with-vim-plug/

File: https://onlinegdb.com/ByyfKgK6w (raises an error, but syntax is fine), system is Manjaro ARM.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax error is happening because the function call is passing an `async=True` keyword argument. The `async` term has become a reserved keyword in recent Python, so it's not allowed as a keyword argument anymore.

If you load this source code in a Python interpreter, it's quite possible that it won't complain about it right away. Python is an interpreted language and many errors (such as this one) will only be raised when the code is actually executed.

If you go to the [roxma/nvim-completion-manager](https://github.com/roxma/nvim-completion-manager) page, you'll see a warning telling you that this repo is deprecated and you should use [ncm2](https://github.com/ncm2/ncm2) instead.

So update your `init.vim` to replace the `roxma/nvim-completion-manager` with:

```
Plug 'ncm2/ncm2'
```

The source code has changed considerably in `ncm2`, but a similar line is still around, but now [using `async_` with a trailing underscore](https://github.com/ncm2/ncm2/blob/3de17695c58f309642c5148b21d47fac61937a96/pythonx/ncm2.py#L218,L220) as the keyword argument name:

```
def complete(self, ctx, startccol, matches, refresh=False):
    self.nvim.call('ncm2#complete', ctx, startccol,
                   matches, refresh, async_=True)
```